# BOW Chunking dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, tfidfvectorizer, countvectorizer

I am attempting chunk my data set while using countvectorizer and TfidfVectorizer. Here is what I have so far.

```
def BOW(data):

    df_temp = data.copy(deep = True)
    df_temp = basic_preprocessing(df_temp)

    #number of words in each chunk
    num_words = 2000
    chunks = []
    counter = 0

    df_temp = splitter(df_temp['text'], num_words)

    for text in df_temp:
        chunk = {'index': counter, 'text': text}
        chunks.append(chunk)
        counter += 1

    count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df = 0.85)

    count_vectorizer.fit([chunk['text'] for chunk in chunks])

    list_corpus = df_temp["text"].tolist()
    list_labels = df_temp["class_label"].tolist()

    X = count_vectorizer.transform(list_corpus)

    return X, list_labels
```

Not sure if this is correct or not. Here are the links to where I tried to reproduce.

[How to avoid memory overloads using SciKit Learn](https://medium.com/@AgenceSkoli/how-to-avoid-memory-overloads-using-scikit-learn-f5eb911ae66c)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? "chunking" includes all kinds of things. You should provide sample input and output.

Comment: @polm23 My overall goal is try to reduce memory usage with CountVectorizer and TfidfVectorizer. I would like to chunk my corpus so I can avoid memory error. I' m aware of some of the hyperparameters that I can adjust to achieve this. However, I would like to test this approach.